$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+a_{n-1}+1$ relation with Fibonacci sequence
I am learning SICP. I am stuck at exercise-1.20

num_b(k+1) = num_b(k) + num_b(k-1) + 1
Obviously we could get
num_b(k) = fib(k+1) - 1

In the following, I will use latex to render the above equation
I think it is wrong since $\text{num}_b(2)=0+1+1=2$ which is not equal to $\text{fib}(2+1)-1=2-1=1$.
Although we can solve $\text{num}_b(n)$ directly $$\text{num}_b(n)=\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{10}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{10}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n} - 1$$ while
$$\text{fib}(n)=- \frac{\sqrt{5} \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}}{5} + \frac{\sqrt{5} \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}}{5}$$
it is not strict to see their relation.
Here $+1$ will be accumulated in recursion and accumulation amount is larger when $k$ becomes larger. Then how to catch it and find the relation between $\text{num}_b$ and $\text{fib}$?

As the comment says, I manually make indices of $\text{num}_b$ are same as $\text{fib}$. As the first link says, $\text{num}_b$ starts from 1 instead of 0 although in SICP book $\text{fib}$ starts from 0.

num_b(1) = 0
num_b(2) = 1


(Strong) hint: you can equivalently write it as $a_{n+1} + 1 = a_n + 1 + a_{n-1} + 1$.

@TheoBendit Thanks very much. I understand now. Strong as you says. My above error is due to using the wrong index for $\text{num}_b(n)$. $\text{num}_b(n)$ starts from 1 and $\text{num}_b(2)=1$.

You can make it tottally general. $$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+a_{n-1}+k$$ Let $a_n=b_n+c$ and replace to get $$b_{n+1}=b_{n}+b_{n-1}+(k+c)$$ Choose  $c=-k$

What are the first two terms?

@J.G. My mistake. Here I uses the wrong first two terms. I will update my question to say that.

You've been given some useful solutions, but they are strictly ad hoc answers. It will help to think in more general terms because tomorrow's problems may not be as simple as today's. So consider a general problem such as
$$
f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}+c.\quad \text{with } f_{0,1} \text{ given}
$$
You can assume a solution of the form
$$
f_n=g_n+C
$$
and find by substitution that
$$
g_n=ag_{n-1}+bg_{n-2}\quad \text{with } g_{0,1}=f_{0,1}-C \text{ given, and}\\
C=aC+bC+c \text{ or } C=\frac{c}{1-a-b}
$$
I'm assuming that you can solve the homogenous equation for $g$. However, notice that this solution fails if $a+b=1$. Mathematically, that's because $C$ is equal to one of roots of $g$. In that case, you go back to
$$
f_n=g_n+C\cdot n
$$
and proceed similarly.

If you want to highlight generality, you might discuss how to write the general solution with arbitrary forcing using convolution, instead of undetermined coefficients.

@lan I learnt convolution last time when learning signal processing which doesn't use the term "forcing". Following https://web.uvic.ca/~tbazett/diffyqs/convolution_section.html, do you mean we get the solution for arbitrary $c$?
